# Making terrain contours in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, maps, data-visualisation

I'd like to take the fantasy world map I created to the next level as a way of buffing my illustrator skills and portfolio.

Currently, it's a flat political map like [this map of Canada](http://www.gov.mb.ca/jec/invest/busfacts/images/canbig.jpg) for example.

[image: Map of Canada Flat]

I'd like to add terrain contours to make it more interesting, like what was used in this map here to show the relative depths of the water:

[image]

This is obviously not done by hand. What software or data processing tool would be used to generate it and export it to illustrator?

(I realize this hovers on the fence between this Stack Exchange and the GIS one. If this isn't the place, then I'll ask it there)

Comment: I think it's indeed better to ask this at http://gis.stackexchange.com/ or even at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Honestly it looks like the example map just used a vector layer with a low opancy, and just copyed, and pasted, and modifyed and I would never be able to tell if it was correct or not, but it dose look good.